# Navigating from Area to Non-Area view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have some controllers in a non-Area controller folder and I have some controllers in the Areas/Controllers folder.

For example: I have EquipmentController, ContractsController in the Controllers folder (non-Area)

I have a controller called SiteManagement in the Areas/Controllers folder.

I can navigate to Equipment (http://localhost:3384/Equipment) , Contracts (http://localhost:3384/Contracts) and SiteManagement (http://localhost:3384/SiteManagement/UsersAdmin) view page without any issues. However when I click on SiteManagement link, I cannot navigate back to Equipment or Contracts page because their links are appended with SiteManagement/Contracts or SiteManagement/Equipment and I get a page not found error.

I know that there is an issue with the routing. How do I fix this issue?

Sample code from the Layout page (which is located in Views/Shared folder)

```
<li class="has-sub">
    <a href="collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="icon-doc-text"></i><span class="title">Contracts</span></a>
    <ul class="nav collapse">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Contract")"><span class="title">Create New Contract</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contract")"><span class="title">View Contracts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub">
    <a href="collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="icon-doc-text"></i><span class="title">Equipment</span></a>
    <ul class="nav collapse">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Equipment")"><span class="title">Create New Equipment</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Equipment")"><span class="title">View Equipment</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="has-sub">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Admin")" title="Adminstrator" aria-expanded="true">
        <i class="icon-layout"></i><span class="title">Adminstrator</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav collapse">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "UsersAdmin", new {Area="SiteManagement" })"><span class="title">Users</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "RolesAdmin", new {Area="SiteManagement" })"><span class="title">Roles</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Route Config code

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

SiteManagement Area Registration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "SiteManagement_default",
                "SiteManagement/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            }
```

Expected result: 
I would like to be able to navigate between area sites and non-area sites easily.

Comment: Can you try and set the controller without area to be like this, for example, @Url.Action("Create", "Contract", new {Area=" " ) and see if it will work

Comment: yes that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller not Within Area can be set for example below**

```
*set the Area Empty*

@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new {Area=""} )
```

So in your case, we can have:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Contract", new {Area=""})"><span class="title">Create New Contract</span></a>
```

Below is how my route config looks like. it might be helpful too

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", // Route name
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks